# How to create a shared navigation bar to inter-navigate among multiple views in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to navigate among screens A, B, and C by tapping the corresponding button in a shared navigation bar at the bottom of every screen. How can I create such a toolbar to achieve this inter-navigability among screens?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `TabView {...}` to accomplish this. Effectively you instantiate your views inside of the `TabView` then add an item modifier to each view.

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Text("A")
            .tabItem { Text("A") }
        Text("B")
            .tabItem { Text("B") }
        Text("C")
            .tabItem { Text("C") }
    }


    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

What this code does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKBHm.gif

For added clarity, you can add any item you want to a TabView. It basically acts as a container for the views that you add.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            FirstView()
                .tabItem { Text("A") }
            SecondView()
                .tabItem { Text("B") }
            ThirdView()
                .tabItem { Text("C") }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("A")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("B")
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("C")
    }
}
```

### Custom Tab Bar

This is a very simple case where we simply swap out the parent `VStack{}` based on the enum that we created. When it's first initialized this would set the `.first` page and that would be the one displayed. Anytime we change it with a button action located in the `HStack{}` the view is updated. This is especially useful if you want to add something more to the tab bar beyond text or an image. You could also add the `selectedPage` to an `@EnvironmentObject` to have control of those pages from anywhere in the app. It's especially useful when creating logins or landing pages, where you need to swap the navigation stack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedPage: SelectedPage = .first
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                switch selectedPage {
                case .first:
                    FirstView()
                case .second:
                    SecondView()
                case .third:
                    ThirdView()
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: { selectedPage = .first }, label: {
                    Text("A")
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: { selectedPage = .second }, label: {
                    Text("B")
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: { selectedPage = .third }, label: {
                    Text("C")
                })
            }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
        }
    }
}

enum SelectedPage {
    case first, second, third
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In reality views A, B and C are to be home, settings, and profile screens which interact with the user and each have buttons of their own. However, TabView seems confined to tabs that can only accept Image and Text views, not buttons, etc. Any ideas for implementing navigation among more complex Views?

Comment: So you're wanting a custom Tab bar, not necessarily native? I can also show you how to do that. Give me a few to get that built. Gonna go grab lunch real quick.

Comment: @cbusch the content views of each tab can be any collection of SwiftUI views you want.  The tab bar itself only has text and an icon for selecting the tab.

Comment: @Paulw11 Awesome, thank you for pointing that out. How would I modify the background of the TabView? I'd like to wrap the tab buttons in a colored frame, but the .background(Color.black) modifier called on TabView fails to render its background black.

Comment: @cbusch there you go :D